On étaient tous copains
Le pronom indéfini on est singulier. Cependant, il peut servir à représenter plusieurs personnes. Dans ce cas, pourrais-je écrire on étaient tous copains, par abus, pour bien marquer qu'il y a là plusieurs personnes?
Il me paraît presque plus naturel d'utiliser le pluriel que le singulier dans ce cas. C'est un peu comme si on n'était là que pour former une expression plus ou moins "figée", alors que les copains porte la véritable sémantique du sujet.

Depuis 20ans je n'utilise plus "on" et il ne me manque aucunement. Si je l'entends dans une conversation je fais silence jusqu'à ce qu'elle passe à un autre sujet: depuis, quelle paix! quelle sérénité!

Pour l'attribut ("tous copains") ou un participe, oui.
Pour le verbe, non, cela reviendrait à dire "on sont tous copains" au présent.
https://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#60_strong-em-on-nous-vous-accord-em-strong

Pour l'attribut, je ne vois pas trop d'autre solution.

On pourrait imaginer qu'"on" est le mauvais pronom et qu'il faut utiliser "nous", mais il est bien valable donc en effet pas d'autre solution.
